# OneDrive Upload API, resumeable uploading does not work on web

Tags: onedrive

I have developed web apps. http://onedrive.booogle.net/

> The resumeable uploading for OneDrive API does not work on web. Simple
>   item uploading only works (100M limit). "Request header field
>   Content-Range is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers."

error occurs on Chrome, Firefox...
Is it bugs? How to fix it?

```
function _upload_send(uploadUrl){
    var cfiledata='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    var body=btoa(cfiledata);
    var start=0;
    var end=cfiledata.length;
    var len=cfiledata.length;

    xhr.open('PUT', uploadUrl);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + md_access_token);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Range', 'bytes '+start+'-'+(end-1)+'/'+len);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Encoding', 'base64');     
    xhr.onload = function(){
        //Request header field Content-Range is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.
    };
    xhr.onerror = function(e){   
        //Request header field Content-Range is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.
    };                  
    xhr.send(body);     
}
function _upload_create(){
    filename='largefile.txt';
    xhr.open('POST', 'https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0'+'/drive/items/'+upload_id+':/'+encodeURIComponent(filename)+':/upload.createSession');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + md_access_token);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    var body={
      "item": {
        "@name.conflictBehavior": "rename",
        "name": filename
        }
    };
    xhr.onload = function(){
        if(this.status==200){
            try{
                var a=JSON.parse(this.response);
                if(a.uploadUrl){
                    _upload_send(a.uploadUrl);
                }
            }catch(err){}
        }
    };
    xhr.onerror = function(e){   
    };
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(body));     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug. Thanks for reporting it. Tracking with https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/issues/157. We'll fix it soon.

-- update --

This is now fixed.